# Как в angular ui-router менять url в пределах одного view?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, ui-router

Внутри view находятся контроллеры для выбора городов и параметров. И в этом же view должны показываться выбранные объекты выбранных городов. Когда загружается view, анализируется url и на основании параметров делается запрос на сервер. Заранее неизвестно, какие именно параметры будут выбраны. Поэтому url страницы должен быть примерно таким: http://site.com/cities?cityId=3&cityId=33&param1=value1.
В связи с этим вопросы:

1. как правильно поместить этот url в location?
2. на какое событие написать обработчик, что бы поймать такой переход?

Comment: Непонятно зачем ловить такой переход? при переходе инициализируется контроллер, и все действия можно в нем делать

Comment: @Grundy, переходы в 99% осуществляются внутри этого же вью.

Comment: вообще view никак к url Не относится. Но нужен просто [mcve]

Comment: @Grundy, большущее спасибо, но я уже нашел для себя рабочее решение.

Comment: скорее workaround :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. В $stateProvider

   ```
   .state('cities', {
         url: "/cities?cityId&cityId&someParam",
         templateUrl: "...."
       })
   ```
2. Вызов:

   ```
   $state.go('cities', {/* params */}, {location: true})
   ```
3. Перехватывается и парсится на событии:

   ```
   $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function () {
     console.log($location.$$url)
   }
   ```

Comment: почему `viewContentLoaded` а не `statechangesuccess`?

Comment: @Grundy, Вы правы. Исправил.